# How can I draw a road using bing maps api?

Tags: gis, bing-maps

Is it possible to draw a road using bing maps js api? Ideally I would supply two georeference points and the trajectory/road would be always on the same road.

Basically, I want to highlight a road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map.GetDirections(new VELatLong(lat,lon),new VELatLong(lat,lon))`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Get a multi-point route" sample in the [interactive SDK under Get a multi-point route and directions](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/).

This is the relevant function call:

```
map.GetDirections(["Microsoft", "Everett WA", "Bellingham WA"]);
```